# Replace Single Column Value in Single Row in Sqlite with iPhone App

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sqlite

I just started work with sqlite in iPhone application. Now the Question is I have 3 columns in Table. ID,Channel_Name and Channel_IP. Here is table Example.

```
ID  |   Channel_Name  |  Channel_IP   
1   |   XYZ           |  http://0.0.0.0/indez.sdp/playlist.m3u8
2   |   ABC           |  http://0.0.0.0/index.sdp/playlist.m3u8
```

Now i Just want to update the IP address in Channel_IP Column not the whole only the IP Address in the URL Link(like update 0.0.0.0 to 1.1.1.1 only IP Address). Also Search on Google but not found any relevant solution so if any know please let know.

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USE below query

```
UPDATE yourtableName SET  Channel_IP = replace(Channel_IP, '0.0.0.0', '1.1.1.1');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support.